# CodeIgniter controllers are not loading and giving a 404 error

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I am testing  gocart (http://gocartdv.com/) and I have installed it in a subfolder called vine-cart, http://www.icas-v.org/vine-cart.

The default controller loads fine but the rest of the controllers return an error 404 message. I have looked through all the similar problems and the possible solutions, implemented them and they don't seem to work.

Please have a look at my configuration settings:

/*---------------------------------|.htaccess file  settings|---------------------------------*/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /vine-cart

### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs

# If your default controller is something other than
# "welcome" you should probably change this
RewriteRule ^(cart(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

###

# Removes access to the system folder by users.
# Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
# previously this would not have been possible.
# 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
# such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
# request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

# Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

/*---------------------------------|Config.php settings|---------------------------------*/

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.icas-v.org/vine-cart/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

/*---------------------------------|routes file  settings|---------------------------------*/

```
$route['default_controller']    = "cart";
//this for the admininstration console
$route['admin']                 = 'admin/dashboard';
$route['admin/media/(:any)']        = 'admin/media/$1';
```

Ive been trying to debug this for days. Please help.

Comment: Anything in the error logs? What are the URL's you want? What are the URL's you are getting? What are those first two RewriteRule's doing? http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/urls.html > Removing index.php

Comment: What happens if you add a / before index.php on your last RewriteRule?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this htaccess code? remove rewritebase.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /vine-cart/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /vine-cart/ [L]
</IfModule>
```

What did you name your controller file?

Also it's a good practice to comment out lines on your .htaccess as you test them 1 by 1 if its causing issues.